Tailwind CSS Peer and :nth-of-type combination
Can anyone please explain to me why the display: block property is only applying to div "1" and "2", but not to the other ones (3, 4 and 5)? I would very much appreciate any insights and corrections here.
<div className='text-zinc-800'>

  <div className="peer">0</div>

  <div className="hidden peer-[:nth-of-type(1)_&]:block w-[300px] h-[50px] neon-orange bg-slate-200">1</div>

  <div className="hidden peer-[:nth-of-type(2)_&]:block w-[300px] h-[50px] neon-orange bg-slate-200">2</div>

  <div className="hidden peer-[:nth-of-type(3)_&]:block w-[300px] h-[50px] neon-orange bg-slate-200">3</div>

  <div className="hidden peer-[:nth-of-type(4)_&]:block w-[300px] h-[50px] neon-orange bg-slate-200">4</div>

  <div className="hidden peer-[:nth-of-type(5)_&]:block w-[300px] h-[50px] neon-orange bg-slate-200">5</div>

</div>

I was just trying to wrap my head around the use of complex selections and the & operator together.

display: block should only be applied to div 1, as evidenced by this Tailwind Play. If this is not the case for you, it seems like there could be some other CSS at work applying display: block to div 2.
